# Why is my selenium grid hub only accepting 1 instance of Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I can't figure out why I am unable to get a Selenium Grid Hub to accept more than one session instance of firefox.   I configured it correctly, as far as I know and all I get is a hub that will only take 1 instance.

```
java.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar -role hub -browser 
"browserName=firefox,version=19,firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla
 Firefox\firefox.exe ,maxInstances=5, platform=WINDOWS" -debug
```

It shows an error saying it only can take 1 instance:

```
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Feb 26, 2013 7:31:56 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid server
2013-02-26 19:32:02.605:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2013-02-26 19:32:02.643:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2013-02-26 19:32:02.649:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444
Feb 26, 2013 7:32:05 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>
WARNING: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
```

What????

[More detailed log here](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5044872).

My hub starter files [are here, on GitHub](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/tree/master/root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the hub need not be started with the browser details.  Its the node which needs to be started with the browser specifications.

For the hub starting, you would just need
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar -role hub.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer turned out to be that, specifically in the Node JSON config file, I needed to put maxSessions in the configurations section (instead of maxInstances, which is a capability).  I was putting it in the Hub JSON config, as the docs suggested, but it turns out that the docs do not discriminate between the two configs and I had to figure it out myself.  Now I finally have an example working of parallel browsers running.  See the config files in the link I provided above.